# Aggregate in Axon vs Actor in AKKA

Tags: java, akka, axon

I used Axon framework recently in implementing micro service based on event-sourcing.  Axon has Aggregate definition that i think is very similar to actor in Akka.
is there any different between Actor in AKKA and Aggregate in AXON?

Answer (score 5):

Both Axon Aggregates and Akka actors are capable of processing "Command Messages" if you are using the CQRS/ES pattern. While Akka is based on the Actor Threading model, Axon is based on Java. A deeper dive into the differences can be found in this article on AxonIQ's website -> https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/axon-and-akka---how-do-they-compare . This gives a far more holistic comparison of the two platforms.

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Great explanation, Vijay :)